# Is there a way to remove a public repo and all it's forks on GitHub ?

Tags: git, github

I know GitHub only deletes forks from private repos, but if I were to make this repo private and then delete it, would it delete everything then?

I'm also willing to settle on not having my name on the repo as well.. if the former is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I haven't found a way to do this exactly - once it's out there, it's out there. If the repo hasn't been forked, you can delete it. However, if it's been forked and you'd like to delete your association with it, you can create another account, OR you can hand over admin privileges to another user, either way, it's the same as deleting it from your personal repository. Your username will still be visible inside the repo that's been forked.

Wish GitHub would create a process where we can ping people who have forked it, to delete it, or at least delete our name from it automatically when we delete it, or at least give us that option.

Answer (score 1):

That is something we just can't answer fully, as it depends in part on github's policy. But if you publish a repo there, anybody can clone it. There will be no way to take that back later, no even with github's full cooperation.